How to make Homebrew directories writeable by multiple users?
I have two users on my Mac. Both are admins. One which can only access certain things which I use for doing work, and one general purpose.
I program in both modes often, but I need to use homebrew packages, and every time I run brew doctor in either, I get this message.
Warning: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
/usr/local/share/aclocal
/usr/local/share/doc
/usr/local/share/info
/usr/local/share/locale
/usr/local/share/man/man3
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7
/usr/local/share/man/man8
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks
/usr/local/var/log

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R lucasgreenwood1661 /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks /usr/local/var/log

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share/aclocal /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks /usr/local/var/log

I respond by running the two commands, and that solves the issue for my current user, but it is tedious and needs to be redone after switching back to the other user.
Is there a way for me to make these directories writable by both users?

Admin users can access anything anyway, so I'm  not sure what you accomplish by having two.

Adding as a comment as I'm not sure about this answer, but could you: 1) add a group (e.g. "brewgrp"), make the desired directories have "group ownership" by that group (e.g. sudo chown -R :brewgrp /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks), and make sure the group has write access ((sudo, if needed) chmod g+w /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks)?  Note that some of that stuff, like /usr/local/share/man/man8 looks like it might get used by more than just Homebrew, so a more generic group name is more reasonable, e.g. trusted)

@TOOGAM how would you ensure that newly created files (out of a brew install …) would have the right group set?

hence why I made my response a comment, rather than a graded answer.  I suppose ongoing manual efforts may be the technically-correct-though-painful answer, but I will bow out from suggesting that is a good plan, on account of some more limited amount of familiarity with some specific software.

Homebrew should only be maintained by one (admin) account, you will run into permission and other issues otherwise.
On my Macs, I solved this by setting up a password-less ssh login from my main (non-admin) account into my admin account and then using ssh admin@localhost brew ... to run any Homebrew commands. You can also alias this as alias b='ssh admin@localhost brew' and then run things like b update.

This sounds like a great idea, based on my knowledge of Unix platforms.  Using OpenSSH, a configuration file can specify a public SSH key and what command it runs, while sudo can limit elevation to only commands that start with specific things.  It can be an effective way to get around some permissions issues, without opening permissions up too much more broadly which could enable many other (potentially attacking) activities.

@TOOGAM on macOS, you can‘t limit admin users from running things.

nohillside: No, but a program like OpenSSH can only allow a key to perform a certain command, and a program like sudo can check the start of the command. So I would expect that you could restrict a non-admin user from elevating unless certain criteria is met (unless such restrictions are not feasible because sudo is actually open to everybody to run it, without a password or other relevant restrictions that sudo can normally check).  So, neither of the approaches I mentioned were about limiting an "admin user" (who already is operating with active administrative rights).
